# Facebook login button ins't working for IE

Tags: facebook

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
    FB.init({
        appId: '#',
        status: true,
        cookie: true,
        xfbml: true,
        oauth: true
    })
    FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
        if(response.status === 'connected') {
            var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
            alert(uid);
            FB.api('/' + uid, {
                fields: 'name,email,id,picture'
            }, function (result) {
                //Code
            })
        }
    })
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function (response) {
        // do something with response
        login();
    });
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function (response) {
        logout();
    });
    FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
        if(response.session) {
            // logged in and connected user, someone you know
            login();
        }
    });
};

function login() {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
        if(response.status === 'connected') {
            var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
            // alert(uid);
            FB.api('/' + uid, {
                fields: 'name,email,id,picture'
            }, function (result) {
                //code
            })
        }
    })
}

function logout() {
    //code
}
(function () {
    var e = document.createElement('script');
    e.type = 'text/javascript';
    e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js';
    e.async = true;
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
}());
```

I use the `<div class="fb-login-button">Sign in with Facebook</div>` for the login button to appear.

I have put this script in a JS file and i'm using it on my JSP.

I get a login authentication screen in firefox and chrome, but somehow the button doesn't show in IE 7,8,9

Comment: @Jam what beautifier did you use?

Comment: @Martin. [jsbeautifier.org](http://jsbeautifier.org/)

Comment: @Jam me too, but for some reason, it did keep 8 spaces at the start

Comment: @Martin it will indent the code relative to how far the first line is indented, so for a whole indent of four spaces, you just lrepend four spaces to the beginning of the first line.

Comment: See this links: [link1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2957914/facebook-like-button-showing-in-firefox-but-not-showing-in-ie) [link2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4116711/fblogin-button-problems-with-ie8-internet-explorer-only)

Answer (score 0):

Idk if this is your problem or not, but you might try adding:

```
<html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
```

To your html document

An explanation here:

http://www.zolton.org/2011/04/facebook-fbml-tags-fail-to-load-in-ie/